# Can postgres (SQL) calculate how similar two strings are?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables of tags, that need be joined by a multiple tag columns that are not exact (different capitalization, delimiters handling, order, etc.)

There are also a lot of different fields may be null and the tables have to compared only on non null values.

Table 1

```
     tags1      |          tags2         | tags3 
----------------+------------------------+-----------
 jhon, paul     | null                   | corn, jhon, bloke
 null           | horse, joke, bloke     | Aristoteli, JANEH fonda
```

Table 2

```
     ids        |          names         | clasifiers2 
----------------+------------------------+-----------
 Paul, Jhon     | null                   | corn, Jhon
 null           | Aristoteli, JANEH fonda| horse, joke, bloke
```

Yes, it's a mess.
Is there a function in SQL that would return an index of how close two strings are and would allow to join the two records on only the values that are not null?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/fuzzystrmatch.html

Comment: Join part is still a problem because I don't have an actual ID to merge on but this gets me part but if I figure out how to join this mess I can filter results by some fuzzy matching

Comment: Please provide the desired results, Also if you have anything you have tried post that as well along with the results produced.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function to do that for SQL Server. You can rewrite it for PG. The function name is F_INFERENCE_BASIQUE and you will find the code bellow :
https://sqlpro.developpez.com/cours/sql/comparaisons-motifs/#LVI
I assume that you can read some french.